# Select nearest date on the basis of ID in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table Dispense & Pro Table, I want to select all rows from Dispense table and nearest Shipment date from Pro table.

**Dispense Table**

```
ID       Dispense date  Row ID
604743   10/18/2016     1
604743   11/4/2016      2
604743   11/28/2016     3
604743   12/16/2016     4
```

**Pro table**

```
ID       Shipment Date  Row ID
604743   11/1/2016      1
604743   11/19/2016     2
604743   11/21/2016     3
604743   11/28/2016     4
604743   12/13/2016     5
```

**Output Needed**

```
ID       Dispense date  Pre Ship date
604743   10/18/2016     NULL 
604743   11/4/2016      11/1/2016
604743   11/28/2016     11/19/2016
604743   12/16/2016     12/13/2016
```

Reason for `NULL`: Because less than 10/18 dispense date no nearest date in Shipping date in Pro Table

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (These products hande date/time in different ways.)

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: Why is the nearest Shipment date of 11/28/2016, 11/19/2016 and not 11/21 or 11/28?

Comment: What is the maximum allowed difference (in days) between "Dispense date" and  "Shipment Date". in short what is the maximum value of "nearest Shipment date"

Comment: Hi Jarlh, I am using ms SQL Server.

Comment: Just a word of advice - you're going to be sailing very close to a question ban. I suggest you work on improving your question asking - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Rober, For 11/28 , 11/19 or 11/21 can be anyone but not same date i.e. 11/28. Also if any shipment date is already used then it can't be use no more in next step. For e.g. if we pick 11/21 shipping date for 11/28 dispense date then 11/28 shipping date can be used for 12/16 dispense date.

Comment: Rahul, there is no any fixed allowed days. It could be any but always shipping date should be always less than dispense date.

Comment: "For 11/28 , 11/19 or 11/21 can be anyone" - makes no sense, you clearly stated "**nearest** Shipment date". Please edit your question to reflect the exact requirements.

Comment: "If any shipment date is already used then it can't be use no more in next step" - that kind of complex logic does not belong in your database layer; SQL Server is not optimized for it.

Comment: Hi Helderman. Actually i need any single date from Shipping date which is lower than Dispense date. For e.g. for 10/18 no any Shipping date is lower so it should reflect NULL. For 11/4 dispense date, Shipment date which is lower than 11/4 is only 11/1, so it should reflect 11/1. For 11/28 Dispense date, shipping date can be 11/19 or 11/21 but i can go immediate closer i.e. 11/21. Same for 12/16 dispense date, nearest can be 11/28 or 12/13. But i can take nearest i.e. 12/13. Pls let me know in case you have any other query on this. Also how can i change my question, i can't able to find the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with recursive CTE, but they don't all to use the anchor in a subquery.
So a while-loop is the best I could do.

The script allows for several Dispense or Pro at same date, see the comments on which part you can throw out if that is not allowed by constraints.

```
--- Dispense_Date must not be unique
declare @Dispense table(
    ID int not null,
    Dispense_Date date not null,
    Row_ID int not null identity primary key
)
-- Shipment_Date must not be unique
declare @Pro table(
    ID int not null,
    Shipment_Date date not null,
    Row_ID int not null identity primary key
)
declare @Result table(
    ID int not null,
    Dispense_Date date not null,
    Dispense_Row_ID int not null unique,
    Shipment_Date date not null,
    Pro_Row_ID int not null unique,
    dayDiff int not null,
    Row_ID int not null identity primary key,
    iter int not null
)

insert into @Dispense(ID, Dispense_Date)
values  (604743, '10/18/2016'),
        (604743, '11/4/2016'),
        /* (604743, '11/26/2016'),
        (604743, '11/27/2016'),
        (604743, '11/27/2016'),
        (604743, '11/28/2016'), */
        (604743, '11/28/2016'),
        (604743, '12/16/2016')

insert into @Pro(ID, Shipment_Date)
values  (604743, '11/1/2016'),
        /* (604743, '11/16/2016'),
        (604743, '11/19/2016'), */
        (604743, '11/19/2016'),
        (604743, '11/21/2016'),
        (604743, '11/28/2016'),
        (604743, '12/13/2016')

declare @iter int = 0

while exists(
    select      1
    from        @Dispense Dispense
                inner join
                @Pro Pro
                on  Pro.ID = Dispense.ID
                    and
                    Pro.Shipment_Date < Dispense.Dispense_Date
    where       not exists(
                    select      1
                    from        @Result Result
                    where       Result.Dispense_Row_ID = Dispense.Row_ID
                                or
                                Result.Pro_Row_ID = Pro.Row_ID
                )
)
begin
    set @iter = @iter + 1
    ;   
    with distance(
        ID, Dispense_Row_ID, Dispense_Date, Pro_Row_ID, Shipment_Date, dayDiff
    ) as(
        select      Dispense.ID,
                    Dispense.Row_ID Dispense_Row_ID,
                    Dispense.Dispense_Date,
                    Pro.Row_ID Pro_Row_ID,
                    Pro.Shipment_Date,
                    DATEDIFF(DAY, Pro.Shipment_Date, Dispense.Dispense_Date) dayDiff
        from        @Dispense Dispense
                    inner join
                    @Pro Pro
                    on  Pro.ID = Dispense.ID
                        and
                        Pro.Shipment_Date < Dispense.Dispense_Date
        where       not exists(
                        select      1
                        from        @Result Result
                        where       Result.Dispense_Row_ID = Dispense.Row_ID
                                    or
                                    Result.Pro_Row_ID = Pro.Row_ID
                    )

    )

    insert into @Result(ID, Dispense_Row_ID, Dispense_Date, Pro_Row_ID, Shipment_Date, daydiff, iter)
    select      Dispense.ID,
                Dispense.Row_ID Dispense_Row_ID,
                Dispense.Dispense_Date,
                distance.Pro_Row_ID,
                distance.Shipment_Date,
                distance.dayDiff,
                @iter
    from        @Dispense Dispense
                inner join
                distance
                on  distance.Dispense_Row_ID = Dispense.Row_ID
                    and
                    not exists(
                        select      1
                        from        distance dtExists
                        where       dtExists.ID = distance.ID
                                    and
                                    dtExists.Shipment_Date = distance.Shipment_Date
                                    and
                                    (
                                        dtExists.dayDiff < distance.dayDiff
                                        -- below OR not needed if Dispense_Date and Shipment_Date are unique
                                        or
                                        (
                                            dtExists.dayDiff = distance.dayDiff
                                            and
                                            (
                                                dtExists.Pro_Row_ID < distance.Pro_Row_ID
                                                or
                                                (
                                                    dtExists.Pro_Row_ID = distance.Pro_Row_ID
                                                    and
                                                    dtExists.Dispense_Row_ID < distance.Dispense_Row_ID
                                                )
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                    )
                    and
                    not exists(
                        select      1
                        from        distance dtExists
                        where       dtExists.ID = distance.ID
                                    and
                                    dtExists.Dispense_Date = distance.Dispense_Date
                                    and
                                    (
                                        dtExists.dayDiff < distance.dayDiff
                                        -- below OR not needed if Dispense_Date and Shipment_Date are unique
                                        or
                                        (
                                            dtExists.dayDiff = distance.dayDiff
                                            and
                                            (
                                                dtExists.Pro_Row_ID < distance.Pro_Row_ID
                                                or
                                                (
                                                    dtExists.Pro_Row_ID = distance.Pro_Row_ID
                                                    and
                                                    dtExists.Dispense_Row_ID < distance.Dispense_Row_ID
                                                )
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                    )
end

select      Dispense.ID,
            Dispense.Row_ID Dispense_Row_ID,
            Dispense.Dispense_Date,
            Result.Pro_Row_ID,
            Result.Shipment_Date,
            Result.dayDiff,
            Result.iter
from        @Dispense Dispense
            left join
            @Result Result
            on  Result.Dispense_Row_ID = Dispense.Row_ID
order by    Dispense.ID,
            Dispense.Dispense_Date,
            Result.Shipment_Date,
            Result.Dispense_Row_ID,
            Result.Pro_Row_ID
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Wuodan. You have saved my 3 days. I appreciate your efforts.